# A shell script that can start the multiple copies of same process from different directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to start multiple replicas of same program where each copy of program has different inputs that are stored in separate directories. I tried to write following shell script to start 5 replicas of my program, but it starts only one program. I guess that script does not takes it to move to next directory after it starts program at the first directory. My script is below-

```
! /bin/bash

CODEDIR=../../../..
PROGRAM_BIN=$CODEDIR/bin/PROGRAM


cd 'path_to_directory_1'
$PROGRAM_BIN input1
echo 'Fisrt program has started'

cd 'path_to_directory_2'
$PROGRAM_BIN input2

echo 'Second program has started'

cd 'path_to_directory_3'
$PROGRAM_BIN input3
echo 'Third program has started'

cd 'path_to_directory_4'
$PROGRAM_BIN input4
echo 'Fourth program has started'

cd 'path_to_directory_5'
$PROGRAM_BIN input5

echo 'Fifth program has started'
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. It passed the shellchecker without any warning/error.

Comment: Unless you pasted it wrong, it couldn't have possibly passed.

Comment: Hi ' 4ae1e1'....It does pass. The two warnings that it was  showing, has nothing to do with the problem posed. I have edited to correct those two warning.

Comment: @user2964728 And I have answered. In particular, see the 4th point. By the way, your shebang is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. Shebang is incomplete. `!/bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`.
2. `CODEDIR=../../../..` is really bad practice. This way the script can only be run from one directory.
3. `$ PROGRAM_BIN` should be `$PROGRAM_BIN`. No whitespace.
4. Your real question. Your question reads "I want to start multiple replicas..." I take that as you want to start several long running jobs at once, rather than do them in series. Then you should execute the jobs [in *background*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-background) using the control character `&`.

Corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODEDIR=../../../..
PROGRAM_BIN=$CODEDIR/bin/PROGRAM

cd 'path_to_directory_1'
$PROGRAM_BIN input1 &
echo 'Fisrt program has started' >&2

cd 'path_to_directory_2'
$PROGRAM_BIN input2 &
echo 'Second program has started' >&2

cd 'path_to_directory_3'
$PROGRAM_BIN input3 &
echo 'Third program has started' >&2

cd 'path_to_directory_4'
$PROGRAM_BIN input4 &
echo 'Fourth program has started' >&2

cd 'path_to_directory_5'
$PROGRAM_BIN input5 &
echo 'Fifth program has started' >&2
```

By the way, I understand that certain programs much be run from a certain directory to function properly (I have more than a few scripts like that). However, for most purposes, `cd` is not the greatest idea, and you should put the path in the arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I'll run this script to see if it works as intended.